# python httplib2 connection refused error10061

Tags: python, python-2.7, httplib2

How to how to login and establish the connection with the token ..?
i am getting response as  -->  {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
I tried with requests python library.

Also i am getting the  error "target machine actively refused as given below"
I tried httplib2 , If any one know Kindly help on this..... :-(

```
import httplib2

http = httplib2.Http()
resp = http.request("http://www.something.com", "HEAD")[0]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       resp = http.request("http://www.something.com", "HEAD")[0]   File "C:\Users\vijayakumar.v\Downloads\python-rest-client-0.2.tar\python-rest-client\python-rest-client\httplib2__init__.py",
>   line 1050, in request
>       (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)   File
>   "C:\Users\vijayakumar.v\Downloads\python-rest-client-0.2.tar\python-rest-client\python-rest-client\httplib2__init__.py",
>   line 854, in _request
>       (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)   File
>   "C:\Users\vijayakumar.v\Downloads\python-rest-client-0.2.tar\python-rest-client\python-rest-client\httplib2__init__.py",
>   line 823, in _conn_request
>       conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1057, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1097, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body)   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body)   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 897, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 859, in send
>       self.connect()   File "C:\Users\vijayakumar.v\Downloads\python-rest-client-0.2.tar\python-rest-client\python-rest-client\httplib2__init__.py",
>   line 715, in connect
>       raise socket.error, msg error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

```
http = httplib2.Http()
resp = http.request("http://www.something.com", "GET")[0]
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       resp = http.request("http://www.something.com", "GET")[0]   File "C:\Users\vijayakumar.v\Downloads\python-rest-client-0.2.tar\python-rest-client\python-rest-client\httplib2__init__.py",
>   line 1050, in request
>       (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)   File
>   "C:\Users\vijayakumar.v\Downloads\python-rest-client-0.2.tar\python-rest-client\python-rest-client\httplib2__init__.py",
>   line 854, in _request
>       (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)   File
>   "C:\Users\vijayakumar.v\Downloads\python-rest-client-0.2.tar\python-rest-client\python-rest-client\httplib2__init__.py",
>   line 823, in _conn_request
>       conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1057, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1097, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body)   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body)   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 897, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)   File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 859, in send
>       self.connect()   File "C:\Users\vijayakumar.v\Downloads\python-rest-client-0.2.tar\python-rest-client\python-rest-client\httplib2__init__.py",
>   line 715, in connect
>       raise socket.error, msg error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: Please, write a precise question.

Comment: Updated the questions on description above